# .Find method does not work

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am trying to use .find method to find a particular cell in the datasheet using the following code, which actually worked before, but I don't understand why it is not working this time...

```
Dim targetcell as Range
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate

    Set targetcell = ActiveSheet.Range("A: P").Find(what:="Summary Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

The cell "I79".value = Summary Total

Could anyone help? THANK YOU!

Comment: `Range("A: P")` - try without the space between `:` and `P`

Answer (score 5):

There shouldn't be a space between `"A: P"` and check that there isn't an extra space after "Summary Total" in the cell.